# Can't use props in child component when using Formik for building a wizard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, wizard, formik

I am trying to build a form-wizard. I set up the wizard via `react-router` and used `formik` for the forms. Now I ran into a problem while creating a customizable radio-button. I used the `react-custom-radio` library for that.

When I use the radio-buttons outside of the routes, it is working as it should (code at the bottom of the post).

When I use the with the router, the props are passed down to the child component:

```
<Route path="/form/location" render={(props) => (<Pricing {...props} />)} />
```

Inside the child component, I access the props the same way, as I did it in the parent, where it worked.

```
const Pricing = (props) => {
  const {
    values,
    touched,
    errors,
    setFieldValue,
    setFieldTouched,
  } = props;
  return (
    <div>
        <MyRadio
          value={values.car}
          onChange={setFieldValue}
          onBlur={setFieldTouched}
          error={errors.car}
          touched={touched.car}
        />
    </div>
  );
}
```

But now I always get the error `Cannot read property 'car' of undefined`.
Why doesn't it work if there's a router in between?

If I do it like that, it works:

```
  <Form>
    <Switch>
      <Redirect from="/" exact to="/form/location" />
       <Route path="/form/location" render={(props) => (<Pricing {...props} />)} />
    </Switch>
  <MyRadio
      value={values.car}
      onChange={setFieldValue}
      onBlur={setFieldTouched}
      error={errors.car}
      touched={touched.car}
    />
  </Form>
```

Comment: What happens if you use the `props` of the parent instead, and ignore using the `props` from the `render` function? `() => (<Pricing {...props} />)`

Comment: Cool, it seems to work, but I don't really get what it did. Is this some comparable way of saying this.props?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `props` given to the `render` function are the [route props listed in the documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/route-props). What you want to do in this case is to pass down the `props` from the parent component, not the route props:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { props } = this;
    const {
      values,
      touched,
      errors,
      setFieldValue,
      setFieldTouched,
    } = props;
    return (
      <Form>
        <Switch>
          <Redirect from="/" exact to="/form/location" />
          <Route
            path="/form/location"
            render={() => <Pricing {...props} />}
          />
        </Switch>
        <MyRadio
          value={values.car}
          onChange={setFieldValue}
          onBlur={setFieldTouched}
          error={errors.car}
          touched={touched.car}
        />
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And if you need both Formik's props and this component's you could do:
`render={(formikProps) => <Pricing {...formikProps}, {...props} />}`
That will create a long list of attributes from both props for Pricing to use.